# how do i put full ascii into python script using visual studio code

Tags: python, ascii

this is what i want to put:

```
 ▄▄▄▄    ██▓ ██▓     ██▓   ▓██   ██▓
▓█████▄ ▓██▒▓██▒    ▓██▒    ▒██  ██▒
▒██▒ ▄██▒██▒▒██░    ▒██░     ▒██ ██░
▒██░█▀  ░██░▒██░    ▒██░     ░ ▐██▓░
░▓█  ▀█▓░██░░██████▒░██████▒ ░ ██▒▓░
░▒▓███▀▒░▓  ░ ▒░▓  ░░ ▒░▓  ░  ██▒▒▒ 
▒░▒   ░  ▒ ░░ ░ ▒  ░░ ░ ▒  ░▓██ ░▒░ 
 ░    ░  ▒ ░  ░ ░     ░ ░   ▒ ▒ ░░  
 ░       ░      ░  ░    ░  ░░ ░     
      ░                     ░ ░
```

how do i do it

i tried using print

```
print(" ▄▄▄▄    ██▓ ██▓     ██▓   ▓██   ██▓
▓█████▄ ▓██▒▓██▒    ▓██▒    ▒██  ██▒
▒██▒ ▄██▒██▒▒██░    ▒██░     ▒██ ██░
▒██░█▀  ░██░▒██░    ▒██░     ░ ▐██▓░
░▓█  ▀█▓░██░░██████▒░██████▒ ░ ██▒▓░
░▒▓███▀▒░▓  ░ ▒░▓  ░░ ▒░▓  ░  ██▒▒▒ 
▒░▒   ░  ▒ ░░ ░ ▒  ░░ ░ ▒  ░▓██ ░▒░ 
 ░    ░  ▒ ░  ░ ░     ░ ░   ▒ ▒ ░░  
 ░       ░      ░  ░    ░  ░░ ░     
      ░                     ░ ░     ")
```

but it didnt work

Comment: What do you mean by "full ASCII"? ASCII is just letters used in English, numbers, and a handful of punctuation characters. There are no graphics characters in ASCII.

Comment: You need to use triple quotes to put multiple lines in a string.

Comment: So just change `"` to `"""` and it will work.

Comment: Tangent: ASCII is an encoding standard (i.e. a set of rules about how to convert letters to numbers that computers can work with), and most of the text you work with is just as ASCII as the thing you're trying to print. The thing you're trying to print is specifically _ASCII art_. (Tangent to the tangent: most software uses UTF-8 instead of ASCII these days, so technically what people call ASCII art is usually UTF-8, not ASCII.)

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat: None of the specific block characters they're using are actually part of ASCII, to be clear.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Good point, I recognized the characters as being from the char set that I see people referring to as "extended ASCII", but I didn't understand how _very_ far those chars are from anything resembling ASCII. Turns out that the term "extended ASCII" is so ambiguous and outdated that it's nearly useless as a concept.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat: Yeah, there's a huge variety of Windows code pages for various locales, *all* of which are ASCII supersets. The characters here do appear in a common one, cp437, which is the default used by `cmd.exe` consoles. It uses the upper half of each byte to represent a bunch of blocks and lines for making console "text" art like this. Of course, the rest of Windows (in the English-speaking world) typically uses cp1252 or UTF-16, so those same cp437 bytes would be interpreted very differently if opened in a program expecting cp1252, and would look like gibberish in UTF-16.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't the ASCII that is causing the problem, rather its the way you are trying to print it.

The newline character (`"\n"`) is used to represent ending a line, and moving to the beginning of the next. This doesn't automatically apply when using quotes and simply going to a new line like you've done here. It actually doesn't work at all and will throw an error since the string has to be on one line. There are a few ways to get around this.

The first is simply putting a newline character where you want a line break, and then putting the string into a single line.

```py
print(" ▄▄▄▄    ██▓ ██▓     ██▓   ▓██   ██▓ \n▓█████▄ ▓██▒▓██▒    ▓██▒    ▒██  ██▒ \n▒██▒ ▄██▒██▒▒██░    ▒██░     ▒██ ██░ \n▒██░█▀  ░██░▒██░    ▒██░     ░ ▐██▓░ \n░▓█  ▀█▓░██░░██████▒░██████▒ ░ ██▒▓░ \n░▒▓███▀▒░▓  ░ ▒░▓  ░░ ▒░▓  ░  ██▒▒▒ \n ▒░▒   ░  ▒ ░░ ░ ▒  ░░ ░ ▒  ░▓██ ░▒░ \n  ░    ░  ▒ ░  ░ ░     ░ ░   ▒ ▒ ░░ \n   ░       ░      ░  ░    ░  ░░ ░ \n           ░                     ░ ░ \n     ")
```

Next you could make each line their own string to preserve the shape in the code.

```py
print(" ▄▄▄▄    ██▓ ██▓     ██▓   ▓██   ██▓ \n"
"▓█████▄ ▓██▒▓██▒    ▓██▒    ▒██  ██▒ \n"
"▒██▒ ▄██▒██▒▒██░    ▒██░     ▒██ ██░ \n"
"▒██░█▀  ░██░▒██░    ▒██░     ░ ▐██▓░ \n"
"░▓█  ▀█▓░██░░██████▒░██████▒ ░ ██▒▓░ \n"
"░▒▓███▀▒░▓  ░ ▒░▓  ░░ ▒░▓  ░  ██▒▒▒ \n" 
"▒░▒   ░  ▒ ░░ ░ ▒  ░░ ░ ▒  ░▓██ ░▒░ \n" 
" ░    ░  ▒ ░  ░ ░     ░ ░   ▒ ▒ ░░ \n"  
" ░       ░      ░  ░    ░  ░░ ░ \n"     
"      ░                     ░ ░ ")
```

Finally, to get the print statement to recognize the line breaks automatically, you can use triple quotes instead of single quotes, like so. This creates a string that automatically creates the line breaks where you'd expect.

```py
print(""" ▄▄▄▄    ██▓ ██▓     ██▓   ▓██   ██▓
▓█████▄ ▓██▒▓██▒    ▓██▒    ▒██  ██▒
▒██▒ ▄██▒██▒▒██░    ▒██░     ▒██ ██░
▒██░█▀  ░██░▒██░    ▒██░     ░ ▐██▓░
░▓█  ▀█▓░██░░██████▒░██████▒ ░ ██▒▓░
░▒▓███▀▒░▓  ░ ▒░▓  ░░ ▒░▓  ░  ██▒▒▒ 
▒░▒   ░  ▒ ░░ ░ ▒  ░░ ░ ▒  ░▓██ ░▒░ 
 ░    ░  ▒ ░  ░ ░     ░ ░   ▒ ▒ ░░  
 ░       ░      ░  ░    ░  ░░ ░     
      ░                     ░ ░     """)
```

Comment: [textwrap.dedent](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.dedent) is also useful for preserving indentation while not passing the indentation through to the multiline string

Comment: @RyanHaining: Even more convenient, and usually what you want (no need to always begin with a line continuation on the first line) [is `inspect.cleandoc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.cleandoc). It the more "do what I mean" function; if the first line has no indentation, it ignores it, dedenting based on the other lines. It's the same thing that gets applied to docstrings when formatting them for output.

Comment: @ShadowRanger general text seems outside the intended purpose, and `cleandoc` won't handle it well if the first line should have more indentation than the others (like the first line of a paragraph indented, similarly 4 spaces on the first line and 2 spaces on all others) but in most cases you'll get the same result afaict